# Viewing PHP Pages in Dreamweaver Design Mode

Tags: php, dreamweaver

I built a php site that is hosted with an ISP. A friend who is a designer is supposed to edit the page content. There's an area on the page that is open for page content, but most of the outer "wrapper" is built with include() files.

When she opens the files in design mode, everything is broken. I tried to set up a test server in DW, but this didn't work either. I never use DW and am stuck.

Is it possible to work on a file off of a server via ftp in real time with DW? If not, can it at least be configured to render the php code in design mode somehow?

Thanks,
D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is a server-side language, Dreamweaver is catered toward simple client-side HTML web pages. You would need to setup a PHP interpreter somehow in order for Dreamweaver to show you the output of the PHP, last I recall when I used DW years ago it didn't have that feature, so I doubt you'll be able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

@meder: It appears you are correct for exactly the reasons you stated. The last time I used DW, I was only on the code side, so it never came up. I know we were saving to the server then, so I was thinking it could draw it from the server as well.

Alas, no luck. Sorry to post before I RTFW more.